# How to get Sharepoint user group ,permission level, created , Created by ,Modified, Modified by using CSOM

Tags: csom, sharepoint-permissions

I need to get the User group details.
GroupName, Permissions levels, Created by Created date, Modified by , Modified Date. I am able to get the Group Name and Permission Levels.
How to get the Created by Created date, Modified by , Modified Date in CSOM.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat UserInfoList like normal list and get these information

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://XXXXXXXXXX/");
Web web = clientContext.Web;
List siteUserInfoList = web.SiteUserInfoList;
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "";
IEnumerable<ListItem> itemColl = clientContext.LoadQuery(siteUserInfoList.GetItems(query));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var item in itemColl)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ID:{item.Id}  Created:{item["Created"]} Modified:{item["Modified"]}")
}
```

Comment: Piotr Sulowski: Thanks For your input. My requirement is SiteSetting-->Site Permission, we can see the permissions page. There will be user group permissions are there. I want those data "Created by Created date, Modified by , Modified Date "

Comment: Site Permissions (Role Assigments) are difrent thing than group details. 
SharePoint does not store informations about role assigment date etc.

Comment: Thank you so Much Piotr Sulowski